# Parse json in spark df having variable keys

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark

I need to parse a nested json string which is present as a pyspark dataframe column and fetch required attributed . The issue is  that the key is dynamic .

source df schema:

```
root
 |-- requestid: string (nullable = true)
 |-- page: string (nullable = true)
 |-- payload: string (nullable = true)
 |-- tm: string (nullable = true)
 |-- dt: string (nullable = true)
```

payload is the json string which has the below structure

```
    "Product": {
        "635a49db-3a20-4709-829e-2ddfdf31827c": {
            "configs": {},
            "moduleResponse": [
                {
                    "itemSubstitutes": {
                        "orderId": "",
                        "storeNbr": "1",
                        "customerId": "f180abeb",
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "Item": "1",
                                "IDetails": null,
                                "alternatives": [
                                    {
                                        "id": {
                                            "productId": "5WH3T0LJIQQV",
                                            "Item": "44391040"
                                        },
                                        "itemRank": 1,
                                        "customerChoice": false
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "id": {
                                            "productId": "7GKKVY8SUP54",
                                            "Item": "46521533",
                                           
                                        },
                                        "itemRank": 2,
                                        "customerChoice": false
                                    }
                                ],
                                "prefType": "NO_PREF"
                            }
                        ],
                        "errorItems": []
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

the key `"635a49db-3a20-4709-829e-2ddfdf31827c"` is dynamic which changes. How to parse this json and extract the keys/values present in moduleResponse.itemSubstitutes

```
How can I parse the json and get the below required data:

    customerId |orderId| storeNbr|item_id_rank_1|item_id_rank_2|item_id_rank_3|item_id_rank_4|item_id_rank_5|prefType
    f180abeb   |  null | 1       |44391040      |46521533      |46527634      |4634535       |4652533       |NO_PREF


df.select(f.get_json_object("payload", "Product")).show()
i am getting the error `org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Can't extract value from payload#2462: need struct type but got string;`
```